# jQuery keyup and input event triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have came across similar problems with `touchstart click` events getting triggered twice. I solved it by adding `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` as shown below:

```
    $('.upload-area').on('touchstart click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.upload-button').trigger('click');
    });
```

However, I tried doing the same with `keyup input` event but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: try `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: May you can try with bind and unbind the 'click' event

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may try with `.stop()` jquery function.

Like :

```
$(this).siblings('.upload-button').stop().trigger('click');
```

Or Other way to all `click` and `touchstart` event

```
$('.upload-area').on('touchstart click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.upload-button').trigger('click');
}).stop();
```